# How can I fetch random data from mongodb database using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, fetch

I have made a website which display pictures from my mongodb database but when ever I try to do that I always get the same result but I want that when ever I load my website I should get random data not the same.I am making the project with mongodb database and node.js.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get random document

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]
)
```

docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/